# Building Sencha Touch 2 login system

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to build a multi log in system using Sencha Touch 2, were the user have to select  if he is an AGENT OR FOLLOWER.  so far i have been able to come up with a simple log in form. with no function. my code is just like this:

```
Ext.define("ikhlas.view.login", {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'loginpanel',

    config:{
        title: 'Login',
        iconCls: 'more',
        styleHtmlContent: true,

    layout:{
        type: 'vbox',

        },

    items: [
        {
       xtype: 'fieldset',
       iconCls: 'add',

    items: [

        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name: 'email',
            placeHolder: 'Username'
        },

        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            placeHolder: 'Password'
        },

        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label: 'User Type',
            options: [
            {text: 'Agent',  value: '0'},
            {text: 'Follower', value: '1'}
            ]
        }

   ]},
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'LogIn',
            ui: 'confirm',
            width: '40%',
            height: '7%',
            flex: 1,
            left: '55%',
            action: 'submitContact'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Forgot Username',
            ui: 'confirm',
            width: '41%',
            height: '4%',
            top: '90%',
            flex: 1,
            action: 'ForgotUsername'   
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Forgot Password',
            ui: 'confirm',
            width: '40%',
            height: '4%',
            top: '90%',
            flex: 1,
            left: '47%',
            action: 'ForgotPassword'  
        },
    ]}
});
```

Now i will like to know how do i validate the user information (user name and password) from an API(a url will be given) so as to confirm the login username and password are correct before they can be allowed to access the application. Secondly i will like to throw an error message if the username or password is incorrect.

Comment: What server side language are you going to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that you have to authenticate server-side. Assuming that you've already had one, so the remaining is not very difficult.

The most simple way is just send an `Ext.Ajax.request`:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: your_API_url,
        params: {
                       username: your_username_from_formpanel, 
                       password: your_password_from_formpanel
                    },
        timeout: 10000, // time out for your request

        success: function(result) {
                      // here, base on your response, provide suitable messages
                      // and further processes for your users
        },

        failure: function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert("Could not connect to server.");
        }   
    });
```

Note: for security reasons, you should encrypt your user's password before sending it to server.

Comment: Hi Thiem Nguyen, thanks for the responds, at the moment i havn't  authenticate my server-side, is it possible you can help me out with a PHP script for the Authentication. and secondly how can i encrypt the password? help me out with some scripts. if possible i need a script that can handle SQL injection so as to get the application un -hackable or reduce security treat to the whole application. thanks so much.My database name will be: ikhlas and the table will be ikalas_logs